# Prolog predicate sorting a list with respect to sublist

Tags: sorting, prolog

In prolog I  tried to write a predicate which takes three parameters 
first one is a sublist of second one , third one is the sorted one which includes first parameter and then second with respect to first one.

```
find([a ,c,d] , [a,b,c,d,e,f], Result).
```

Result should be `[a,c,d,b,e,f]`.

My code is not working well

```
find(First,Second,X):-
findall(K, (member(K,Second),
           \+member(K,First),
           append(First,K)), X).
```

Comment: Let me formalize it. `Result = concat( First, sorted(Second-First) )`, right ?

Comment: @mahmutsami106, It's not a very clear example since your second list is already sorted. But I think you mean what EugeneSh. is saying.

Comment: This `append/2` you have there, what is it supposed to be doing? Have you read the documentation to see what `append/2` and `append/3` do?